# EBS FFMPEG Not Installing from ebexentsions

Tags: amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to install FFMPEG on EBS. I have the following in the directory:

`rootfolder/.ebextensions/packages.config`

With the following info inside the file:

```
packages:
  yum:
    ImageMagick: []
    ImageMagick-devel: []

commands:
  01-wget:
    command: "wget -O /tmp/ffmpeg.tar.xz https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-i686-static.tar.xz"
  02-mkdir:
    command: "if [ ! -d /opt/ffmpeg ] ; then mkdir -p /opt/ffmpeg; fi"
  03-tar:
    command: "tar xvf /tmp/ffmpeg.tar.xz -C /opt/ffmpeg"
  04-ln:
    command: "if [[ ! -f /usr/bin/ffmpeg ]] ; then ln -sf /opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-3.4-64bit-static/ffmpeg /usr/bin/ffmpeg; fi"
  05-ln:
    command: "if [[ ! -f /usr/bin/ffprobe ]] ; then ln -sf /opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-3.4-64bit-static/ffprobe /usr/bin/ffprobe; fi"
  06-pecl:
    command: "if [ `pecl list | grep imagick` ] ; then pecl install -f imagick; fi"
```

ut when I sSH into my instang, the ffmpeg command is not installed. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because you are linking wrong version.

You are trying to link:

```
/opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-3.4-64bit-static/ffmpeg
```

However, it should be:

```
/opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-4.3.1-i686-static/ffmpeg
```

Same for `ffprobe`. It should be:

```
/opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-4.3.1-i686-static/ffprobe
```